# What part of CoreGraphics should I use to recreate these effects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, core-animation

The gif below was pulled from Two Dots, an iOS app. If my app is not a game, and I'm using standard UIViews, what is the best way to achieve similar effects in a performance-optimized manner.

I'm specifically referring to the lines shooting out between the circles.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A broad question prompts an unspecific answer: check out [`CAShapeLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/) — its `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` are animatable. So you can set the whole line as the shape, then get Core Animation to animate which segment is displayed.

Comment: Can I just access/modify these properties on a UIView?

Comment: As per the JaredH comment; `CALayer`s are Objective-C so not low level in most senses, but sit below `UIView`s. They're one step down on the graphics stack. You can create a custom view that just holds a particular kind of layer or just use the layers directly as per the example he links to.